# Revoke grant with dblink in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant, postgresql-11, dblink, sql-revoke

I start to use dblink on my postgreSQL 11 db and I have a problem with grant. I can create server and user mapping as superuser , but also I can delete this user mapping and server as usual user. I try to revoke grant from usual user by

`revoke grant option for all on foreign server my_server from not_my_role;`

but it didn't help. How can I do it right?

Comment: dblink is not a fdw, it does not have user mappings.  Please include enough details so we can understand what you are asking, and asking about--such as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If dblink does not have user mapping, why I can't open connection without it? And I can after create user mapping

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, my colleague created user mapping for usual role when he researched postgres_fdw. Probably dblink and postgres_fdw have bond.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).